# Fazer cálculo entre inputs e jogar em uma variável

Tags: javascript

Estou com esse problema, pois não está retornando nada e tentando achar em todos os lugares, porém nada de solução até o momento vou postar os códigos dos meus testes.

Segue:

```js
function calculo(){
   
if (formulario.nome_para.value=="") {
alert("Preencha seu nome corretamente.");
formulario.nome_para.focus();
return false }
 
if (formulario.seu_email.value=="") {
alert("Preencha seu e-mail corretamente.");
formulario.seu_email.focus();
return false }
 
if (formulario.telefone.value=="") {
alert("Preencha seu telefone corretamente.");
formulario.telefone.focus();
return false }
 
if (formulario.endereco.value=="") {
alert("Preencha seu endereço corretamente.");
formulario.endereco.focus();
return false }
 
if (formulario.cidade.value=="") {
alert("Preencha sua cidade corretamente.");
formulario.cidade.focus();
return false }
 
if (formulario.comoConhece.value=="") {
alert("Preencha o campo como conheceu a gente.");
formulario.comoConhece.focus();
return false }
 
var buscaOptionOb = document.getElementById("TipoObra");
var TipoObra = buscaOptionOb.options[buscaOptionOb.selectedIndex].value;
var metro2 = formulario.m2.value;
var limMetro2 = str.match([0-9]/",");
var idadeEd = formulario.idadeEdifica.value;
var limIdadeEd = str.match([0-9]/",");
var tipoObra = formulario.TipoObra.value;
 
var calValRef = tipoObra*limMetro2;
if(limIdadeEd>10){
    calIdade=calValRef*1.2;
}else{
    calIdade=0;
}
if (formulario.reforcoEstru[0].checked) {
    calReforco=calValRef*75.00
}else{
    calReforco=0;
}
var calTot=calIdade+calReforco+calValRef;
document.getElementById('calTotal').value = calTot;    
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return calculo(this);" id="formulario" action="calculoMinuto1.php" method="post"> 
          <div class="col1E">
          <select id="TipoObra"  name="valores">
            <option value="Tipo de obra">Tipo de obra</option>
            <option value="Reforma residencial - Casa">Reforma residencial - Casa</option>
            <option value="Reforma residencial - Apartamento">Reforma residencial - Apartamento</option>
            <option value="Reforma Comercial - Apartamento">Reforma Comercial - Apartamento</option>
            <option value="Reforma Comercial - Casa">Reforma Comercial - Casa</option>
            <option value="Execução de uma nova residência">Execução de uma nova residência</option>
            <option value="Execução de um novo Galpão">Execução de um novo Galpão</option>
            <option value="Execução de um novo estabelecimento comercial">Execução de um novo estabelecimento comercial</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="idadeEdifica" id="idadeEdifica" placeholder="Idade edificação" onKeyUp="mascaraAno(this, event)"  value="">
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="m2" id="m2" placeholder="m²"  onKeyUp="maskIt(this,event,'###.###.###,## m2',true)"  value="">
          <br />
          <select id="reforcoEstru"  name="reforcoEstru">
            <option value="">Reforço estrutural</option>
            <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
            <option value="Não">Não</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <input name="comoConhece" id="comoConhece" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="Como nos conheceu?" />
          </div>
          <div class="col2D">
          <input name="nome_para" id="nome_para" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="Seu nome" />
          <br />
          <input name="seu_email" id="seu_email" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="E-mail" />
          <br />
          <input name="telefone" id="telefone" type="text" class="campo-simples" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" maxlength="15" minlength="10"/>
          <br />
          <input name="endereco" id="endereco" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="Endereço da obra" />
          <br />
          <input name="cidade" id="cidade" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="Cidade" />
          </div>
          <div class="col3T">
          <textarea name="mensagem" rows="3" cols="40" rows="10" class="campo-mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
          <br />
          <strong>Adicionar arquivo</strong><br />
          <input name="arquivo" type="file" class="campo-simples" />
          <br />
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="campo-envia" value="Enviar" />
          </div>
          <input name="assunto" type="hidden" class="campo-cinza" value="Formulario de Orcamento Minuto" />
          <input name="email" type="hidden" class="campo-cinza"value="site@planejarbrasil.com.br" />
          <input name="calTotal" id="calTotal" type="hidden" class="campo-cinza" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="encoding" value="UTF-8">
    </form>
```

Código JS:
https://pastebin.com/CqpqL19N
Código html:
https://pastebin.com/HYegGpMG

Comment: Procure especificar o seu problema criando um [Exemplo Mínimo Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e colocando na pergunta o código relevante ao problema

Comment: Não entendi nada do seu código e nem sobre o seu problema, apenas copiei o que você tinha para o pastebin aqui. Não entendi a sua pergunta e nem o que você está tentando fazer. Mas, não seria o caso de ter um `return true;` no final da sua função `calculo()`?

Comment: Esse é um sistema de calculo que apos a verificação eu pego e envio para uma outra pagina e nessa outra pagina tem um sistema para envio de email. Montei a logica do codigo de como ele devia funcionar, porém não funciona

Comment: Vou explicar por partes, para que vocês entendam melhor e possam me ajudar.

Comment: `var limMetro2 = str.match([0-9]/",");` de onde vem esse `str`? Essa regex está mal formatada precisa de `/` no inicio e fim.

Comment: Não está faltando um `var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");` no começo da função `calculo()`?

Comment: O campo TipoObra ele tem alguns valores pre definidos que vai ser multiplicado pelo m2, gerando assim um total, entretanto tem alguns ifs, se idadeEdifica for maior que 10 é acrescentado um valor a mais e se for ticado o campo reforcoEstru como sim é acrescentado mais outro valor, é tudo isso é acrescentado em uma variavel total

Comment: m2 e idadeEdifica tem mascaras

Comment: Sou muito leigo em JS estou estudando ainda, esse codigo copiei em partes e tentei montar usando logica, str < não sei o que significa, agora que falou estou jogando no google para uma pesquisa, deixa dessa forma então var limMetro2 = match(/[0-9]/","/);

Comment: Se eu escolher a opção `Reforma Comercial - Casa`, ele vai pegar esse texto e multiplicar pelo metro quadrado. Não tem sentido multiplicar um texto por uma área. Como é que o tipo da obra deveria ser utilizado no cálculo?

Comment: Tentei atribuir valores a casa caso do case, porém sem sucesso, tenho que declarar de forma diferente? lembrando que meu value não posso passaros numeros, pois quando chegar para enviar para o email so chegaria numeros e não texto.

Comment: Sim não teria sentido mesmo multiplicar texto, porém tenho que passar como value por conta da hora de enviar o email, estou tentando anexar valor pelos cases

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, usamos `parseInt` para **tentar** obter um número a partir de um valor texto. Entretanto, se o usuário digitar `abc` no campo numérico, o `parseInt` vai falhar e retornar `NaN`. É aí que entra a função `isNaN` que serve para determinar se o valor digitado é mesmo um número.

Uma outra coisa é que coloquei uma função para validar se um campo está em branco, para evitar copiar e colar código.

Criei uma função `valorDeRefPorTipoDeObra` que diz qual é o valor de referência do metro quadrado de acordo com o tipo da obra. Esta função provavelmente está errada, mas deve ser fácil para você ajustar os valores adequados nela.

Não sei se o cálculo produz os números corretos (mesmo se a função `valorDeRefPorTipoDeObra` estivesse correta), mas ele valida os campos e mostra o resultado calculado do total de cal. Ele também retorna `true` quando é válido e `false` quando não for. Parti do pressuposto de que as fórmulas que você deu estavam corretas.

O código ficou esse abaixo. Lá em baixo tem um botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> que você pode usar para testar este código.

Ficou assim:

```js
// Desativadas apenas para poder simular abaixo.
function maskIt() {}
function mascaraAno() {}

function validaErroBranco(campo, mensagem) {
    if (campo.value !== "") return true;
    alert(mensagem);
    campo.focus();
    return false;
}

function valorDeRefPorTipoDeObra(tipo) {
    switch (tipo) {
         case 'Reforma residencial - Casa': return 1;
         case 'Reforma residencial - Apartamento': return 2;
         case 'Reforma Comercial - Apartamento': return 3;
         case 'Reforma Comercial - Casa': return 4;
         case 'Execução de uma nova residência': return 5;
         case 'Execução de um novo Galpão': return 6;
         case 'Execução de um novo estabelecimento comercial': return 7;
    }
}

function calculo() {
    var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

    var valido = validaErroBranco(formulario.nome_para, "Preencha seu nome corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.seu_email, "Preencha seu e-mail corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.telefone, "Preencha seu telefone corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.endereco, "Preencha seu endereço corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.cidade, "Preencha sua cidade corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.comoConhece, "Preencha o campo como conheceu a gente.");

    if (!valido) return false;

    var tipoOption = document.getElementById("TipoObra");
    if (tipoOption.selectedIndex === 0) {
        alert("Escolha o tipo da obra.");
        tipoOption.focus();
        return false;
    }

    var reforcoOption = document.getElementById("reforcoEstrutural");
    if (reforcoOption.selectedIndex === 0) {
        alert("Escolha o tipo do reforço.");
        reforcoOption.focus();
        return false;
    }

    var metro2 = parseInt(formulario.m2.value);
    if (isNaN(metro2)) {
         alert("O campo de m² deve ser preenchido com números.");
         formulario.m2.focus();
         return false;
    }

    var idadeEd = parseInt(formulario.idadeEdifica.value);
    if (isNaN(idadeEd)) {
         alert("Os campo de idade edificação deve ser preenchido com números.");
         formulario.idadeEdifica.focus();
         return false;
    }

    var tipoObra = valorDeRefPorTipoDeObra(tipoOption[tipoOption.selectedIndex].value);
 
    var calValorRef = tipoObra * metro2;
    var calIdade = idadeEd > 10 ? calValorRef * 1.2 : 0;
    var calReforco = reforcoOption.selectedIndex === 1 ? calValorRef * 75.00 : 0;
    var calTotal = calIdade + calReforco + calValorRef;
    document.getElementById('calTotal').value = calTotal;
    alert(calTotal);
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return calculo();" id="formulario" action="calculoMinuto1.php" method="post"> 
      <div class="col1E">
          <select id="TipoObra" name="valores">
              <option value="Tipo de obra">Tipo de obra</option>
              <option value="Reforma residencial - Casa">Reforma residencial - Casa</option>
              <option value="Reforma residencial - Apartamento">Reforma residencial - Apartamento</option>
              <option value="Reforma Comercial - Apartamento">Reforma Comercial - Apartamento</option>
              <option value="Reforma Comercial - Casa">Reforma Comercial - Casa</option>
              <option value="Execução de uma nova residência">Execução de uma nova residência</option>
              <option value="Execução de um novo Galpão">Execução de um novo Galpão</option>
              <option value="Execução de um novo estabelecimento comercial">Execução de um novo estabelecimento comercial</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="idadeEdifica" id="idadeEdifica" placeholder="Idade edificação" onKeyUp="mascaraAno(this, event)" value="">
          <br />
          <input type="text" name="m2" id="m2" placeholder="m²" onKeyUp="maskIt(this, event, '###.###.###,## m2', true)" value="">
          <br />
          <select id="reforcoEstrutural" name="reforcoEstrutural">
              <option value="">Reforço estrutural</option>
              <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
              <option value="Não">Não</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <input name="comoConhece" id="comoConhece" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="Como nos conheceu?" />
          </div>
          <div class="col2D">
          <input name="nome_para" id="nome_para" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="Seu nome" />
          <br />
          <input name="seu_email" id="seu_email" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="E-mail" />
          <br />
          <input name="telefone" id="telefone" type="text" class="campo-simples" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" maxlength="15" minlength="10"/>
          <br />
          <input name="endereco" id="endereco" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="Endereço da obra" />
          <br />
          <input name="cidade" id="cidade" type="text" class="campo-simples" placeholder="Cidade" />
          </div>
          <div class="col3T">
          <textarea name="mensagem" rows="3" cols="40" rows="10" class="campo-mensagem" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
          <br />
          <strong>Adicionar arquivo</strong><br />
          <input name="arquivo" type="file" class="campo-simples" />
          <br />
          <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="campo-envia" value="Enviar" />
          </div>
          <input name="assunto" type="hidden" class="campo-cinza" value="Formulario de Orcamento Minuto" />
          <input name="email" type="hidden" class="campo-cinza"value="site@planejarbrasil.com.br" />
          <input name="calTotal" id="calTotal" type="hidden" class="campo-cinza" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="encoding" value="UTF-8">
    </form>
```

Comment: case 'Reforma residencial - Casa':  return 1;
   tipoOption=811.56;
   break;

Comment: Estou tentando atribuir valor a casa case dessa forma porém sem muito sucesso

Comment: @Fernando `case 'Reforma residencial - Casa': return 811.56;`

Comment: consegui fazer o calculo muito obrigado, só tenho uma outra duvida se puder me ajudar, o numero está retornando inteiro sem pontuação nenhuma, você me recomenda utilizar mascara ?

Comment: @Fernando Se você está falando do número do `switch` e por "utilizar máscara", você diz colocar um `.00` no final do número inteiro, isso daí é indiferente, porque para o Javascript os dois são sinônimos. Entretanto, se você estiver falando de máscara no campo m2, isso pode ser uma boa ideia se feito corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function validaErroBranco(campo, mensagem) {
    if (campo.value !== "") return true;
    alert(mensagem);
    campo.focus();
    return false;
}
function valorDeRefPorTipoDeObra(TipoObra) {
    switch (TipoObra) {
         case 'Reforma residencial - Casa':  return 811.56;
         case 'Reforma residencial - Apartamento': return 932.12;
         case 'Reforma Comercial - Apartamento':  return 612.79;
         case 'Reforma Comercial - Casa': return 780.00;
         case 'Execução de uma nova residência': return 2700.00;
         case 'Execução de um novo Galpão': return 1400.00;
         case 'Execução de um novo estabelecimento comercial': return 2350.00;
    }
}
function calculo() {
    var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

    var valido = validaErroBranco(formulario.nome_para, "Preencha seu nome corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.seu_email, "Preencha seu e-mail corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.telefone, "Preencha seu telefone corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.endereco, "Preencha seu endereço corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.cidade, "Preencha sua cidade corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.comoConhece, "Preencha o campo como conheceu a gente.");
    if (!valido) return false;
    var tipoOption = document.getElementById("TipoObra");
    if (tipoOption.selectedIndex === 0) {
        alert("Escolha o tipo da obra.");
        tipoOption.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var reforcoOption = document.getElementById("reforcoEstrutural");
    if (reforcoOption.selectedIndex === 0) {
        alert("Escolha o tipo do reforço.");
        reforcoOption.focus();
        return false;
    }
    var metro2 = parseInt(formulario.m2.value);
    if (isNaN(metro2)) {
         alert("O campo de m² deve ser preenchido com números.");
         formulario.m2.focus();
         return false;
    }
    var idadeEd = parseInt(formulario.idadeEdifica.value);
    if (isNaN(idadeEd)) {
         alert("Os campo de idade edificação deve ser preenchido com números.");
         formulario.idadeEdifica.focus();
         return false;
    }
    var tipoObra = valorDeRefPorTipoDeObra(tipoOption[tipoOption.selectedIndex].value);
    var calValorRef = tipoObra * metro2;
    var calIdade = (idadeEd > 10) ? tipoObra * 1.2 : 0;
    var calReforco = (reforcoOption.selectedIndex === 1) ? metro2 * 75.00 : 0;
    var calTotal = (idadeEd > 10) ? calIdade * metro2 + calReforco : calIdade + calReforco + calValorRef;
    var trasfN = parseFloat(Math.round(calTotal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('calTotal').value = trasfN;
    <?php /*?>alert(calTotal);<?php */?>
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Ficou dessa forma para caso alguém necessite! Muito obrigado Victor Stafusa.